# MASM under Linux?

Tags: linux, masm

Is there a way that I use [MASM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Macro_Assembler) under Linux. Even tough NASM is quite popular under Linux, it still differs for some instruction style on code.

Answer (score 13):

Wiki says

> The MASM32 EULA does not allow its usage in the development of open source software, and only allows it to be run in Windows operating systems.

so it is a no.

Comment: Sounds like an old kind of EULA. Not many Microsoft products have such aggressive license agreements nowadays.

Comment: Also, using MASM32 on Linux does not automatically imply that open source software is developed.

Comment: If the EULA still says "only allows it to be run in Windows operating systems" then it doesn't matter whether or not using it on Linux automatically implies that open source software is being developed.

Comment: well, you can run windows in a VM on linux, so that you don't violate their EULA ;-)

Comment: Could you link this quote to its source? It's rather dubious and is no longer on the wiki.

Answer (score 10):

I use DosBox and it does work fine for me.

Details [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20141115062140/http://www.prashanthpai.com/blog/run-masm-8086-assembler-in-ubuntu-or-windows-7x64-using-dosbox/)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You shouldn't just give a link to another site as an answer, since the site may go out of date in the future. Instead, click the "edit" link on this answer and include the essential parts of the solution from that page here. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259

Comment: @PeterO. It looks like that is exactly what has happened.

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to run MASM under [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/).

Answer (score 5):

MASM dont run with WINE, im running MASM under Virtual Box

Answer (score 3):

Personally I prefer the NASM style, but you can probably run MASM under Wine (or failing that, in a VM). After all it shouldn't need any exotic API calls.

I've been able to run the Win32 NASM binary under Wine on Linux without any problems [long story, no net connection].

If you want to convert Microsoft's OMF binary format to ELF then you should be able to do so using `objcopy`, but you may need to compile in support for the right object formats.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to MASM is [UASM](http://www.terraspace.co.uk/uasm.html).

UASM is a free MASM-compatible assembler based on JWasm.

It works for creating general Linux binaries.
However, shared objects requiring the -fPIC option is not possible with UASM.

Comment: underrated answer!

Answer (score 1):

Run MASM under Wine or see at the wiki that MASM can only run at Windows.

Regards.